# What does "thot" mean and when was it first used?

Tags: meaning, etymology, slang, offensive-language, epithets

The word ***thot*** is [all over Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=thot&src=typd&f=realtime).

The [@lovihatibot Twitterbot](https://twitter.com/lovihatibot) routinely finds it in searches for "I love the word [X]" and "I hate the word [X]", in fact it's the [most hated word](https://twitter.com/lovihatibot/status/412838344788557824) and [third most loved word](https://twitter.com/lovihatibot/status/410666215959703552) (presumably use in one category feeding the other).

Similarly it's the [second most common in @favibot's searches](https://twitter.com/favibot/status/412838354607435776) for "[X] is my new favorite word" (up from [number 5 in October](http://laivakoira.typepad.com/blog/2013/10/twitters-new-favourite-words.html)).

What does *thot* mean?

Where does it come from and when was it first used?

Was there a single person or event which popularised it, and when was it?

Comment: An unreliable alternate theory https://vine.co/v/eqX7gpOvtji

Answer (score 15):

The second definition in JoeBright's answer is correct: *thot* is an acronym that stands for "That Ho Over There." The word has a negative connotation and is such sometimes used as an affectionate insult to close friends, but is almost always used to describe women. *Ho* is commonly misspelled as *hoe*, but intended as a short form for *whore*. It's generally considered [AAVE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English), with multiple examples in hip-hop culture.

Unlike in the case of *YOLO*, where Drake's song "The Motto" popularised it, there seems to be no single event. Rather, the word rose to popularity gradually.

This is going to be long...

---

I did find a song called "[Thot Walk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7am0ZyE8qNk)," performed by artists John Boy, Kayleb, and Yung Cyph, but it was made after *thot* reached its peak popularity on Twitter. (It did start a trend on Vine, but that's another story.)

Examples of characteristics the song states are typically attributed to a *thot*: (couldn't find lyrics, all by ear):

> 0:32 "Showing off her body on her Instagram / just to get a hundred Likes on her picture"

So desperate for attention is this *thot* that she dresses as provocatively as possible to attract as many Likes as possible, most of which come from heterosexual men (for reasons which should be obvious).

> 0:40 "Got no face, but all body"

She has a body considered by society to be physically attractive (large breasts & butt, most likely) yet her face is unattractive. This may be because she has an awkward bone structure, is unkempt with her appearance, or is unskilled at applying makeup in a flattering fashion.

> 0:43 "Go it girl, twerk it, make a movie / If you ain't going to do it for me, do it for the Vine"

It's common on Vine for users to share videos of themselves or others [twerking](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/twerk?s=t). Since some can even experience their 15 minutes of viral video fame as a result of a twerk Vine, the phrase *do it for the Vine* has leverage in persuading someone to do anything they wouldn't normally do (not just twerking) for the sake of humour or interest. I believe, however, that Kayleb is using the phrase with thinly-veiled condescension, thinking of girls who twerk for Vines as gullible or attention-seeking.

> 2:26 "If you one of the thots in the VIP / You'd have fucked the promoter, you don't need no ID"

Those in the VIP section of a club are there most likely either because they have money, fame, or connections to someone associated with the club. John Boy implies that having sexual relations with the promoter is a cheap or dishonest way of getting in.

> 2:32 "She act like a hooker with a cup full of liquor"

Once under the influence of alcohol, a *thot* will become promiscuous (or exchange sexual services for money, I wasn't sure).

---

Along with the concrete examples of *thot* behaviour, these two lines may also be of interest.

> 1:21 "She a thot so she talk like one / She a thot so she walk like one"
>
> 2:20 "You can tell she a thot by the way that she stands"

These two phrases, both without followup, suggest that there is more to being a *thot* than just simply being promiscuous. Part of being a *thot* has to do with  how one carries oneself - perhaps speech patterns, lexicon, gait, posture, and/or body language are all variables in determining whether someone is a *thot*.

---

I've also searched up the word on Twitter to see how it'd be used in context, and while I did see a few instances of it being used as a shortening of *thought* as GEdgar suggested, those were well in the minority.

[image: thot tweet 1]

It is illogical to discard a diamond and replace it with a rock because of the drop in value: by analogy, a *thot* has much lower value than a wife.

[image: thot tweet 2]

Birds of a feather flock together.

[image: thot tweet 3]

*Thot* was clearly being used as an untrue allegation to save face publicly.

[image: thot tweet 4]

Also provides evidence to suggest that a *thot* carries herself differently. Presumably, a woman who "runs game" could very well also be promiscuous, but carries herself in such a way that earns her respect, reverence, or unrequited love.

[image: thot tweet 5]

I can assume from this tweet that the scenario in which a girl previously perceived as beautiful becomes a *thot* is common. The user laments because he believes becoming a *thot* is shameful.

[image: thot tweet 6]

An exception to the rule: Previously used only by men toward women, this is a woman not wanting to associate herself with anything having to do with *thots*.

---

As previously stated, a *thot* is most definitely promiscuous, but considering the evidence, one can start to form a profile.

A *thot* is well-connected on social media, but most likely has received most of her attention from desperate heterosexual men hoping to get an easy lay. Unattractive with a sense of grandeur, or perhaps attractive only with makeup, she barely only looks good enough to attract this attention. She is shameless, dishonest, or not self-aware, with further personal boundaries than most. There are a wide variety of men with whom she is willing to sustain a sexual relationship, reoccuring or not. She twerks, or does any other activity notorious for being a blatantly sexual way of attracting attention. She is a common enough occurrence for her value to have diminished. Her behaviour would be unsuitable in polite company. She befriends other *thots*, while other women who see themselves as better do not wish to associate with her.

Also, *that ho over there* is a phrase that puts physical distance between the narrator and the ho. Extrapolating, it could imply disinterest or detachment, as if the narrator knows there will be another ho over there, and over there, and over there.

And that's a *thot*.

The social implications of the word and its usage are a whole other can of worms, and out of the scope of this site.

Comment: [+1] Clearly explained, and I see you have done a lot of research. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Exactly I don't know what it means on Twitter.
But **thot** has different meanings such as:

> 1. A Thot is a hoe. Plural: Thotties
>
>    e.g : *Marquan: Yo thats my main girl
>
>      Deshaun: She yo main girl but she my main thot*
> 2. THAT HOE OVER THERE
>
>    e.g : *WHO IS THAT?
>
>      aw, shit just a THOT*
> 3. Some stupid shit that people are saying now a days but abreviated from " That hoe over there "
>
>    e.g : *Mike : Yo look at that chick by the stop sign shes fine as hell
>
>      Joe : Naw bruh leave her alone thats a thot*
> 4. A name used to describe a females who frequently hook up and has sex with multiple guys (sometimes in the same night) without being in a relationship with them.
>
>    e.g : *Originally standing for "that hore out there".
>
>      Todd: Did you go to that party last night?
>
>      Nick: Yeah you should've went; there was a lot of thots there.*
> 5. A male or female who would gladly show their package to anybody who has a slight thirst. They quench the citizen's hornieness with no problem at all. Some may refer to a Thot as a whore, slut, broad, etc. Basically (plural) thotties are the ones at the party who are already in a private room within the first hour, getting dirty and exploiting their bodies. Or maybe they just stayed in the main area for everyone to watch.
>
>    e.g : *Joe: hey man did you get laid last night?
>
>          Bob:yeah had to recruit a thot.
>
>          Joe: ah, them thotties are always the easiest!*

Reference: [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thot)

Answer (score 2):

One of those abortive spelling-reform proposals from around 1900. "Through -> thru" and "though -> tho" may have caught on a bit, but "thought -> thot" hasn't,  until (apparently) Twitter-imposed limits on the number of characters in a message.

**Thot** is mentioned [here](http://www.basic-english.org/21/spelling.html).

Comment: So do you think the most common 2013 use of *thot* is an instance of "thought"? Here's the most recent example: "Calling someone a hoe is better than calling them a Thot." // There are some though: "What sneakers did MJ have on in the Hanes commercial....????" but a 3-char saving to appease the Twitter limit wasn't required there.

Answer (score 1):

A *thot* is someone who does something strange for a little bit of change.

Comment: "Thot you do bend your eye on vacancy, And with the incorporeal air do hold discourse?" http://books.google.com/books?id=i2lZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA733&lpg=PA733&dq=%22Thot+you+do+hood+your+eye+on%22&source=bl&ots=HxQ_lpdYG1&sig=jCx5WM0od9fIqO9zBJz0ucuBn9k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_DvdUpC-BseGyAH6rYCoAg&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Thot%20you%20do%20hood%20your%20eye%20on%22&f=false

Comment: So well expressed here that I've got to upvote even though I don't have a clue of the word's general meaning.

Comment: Where's your evidence?